# Selenium IDE FireFox: Simulate CTRL + A on a text field

Tags: firefox, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium's Firefox Plugin IDE as it is much, much faster to write tests with. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do `CTRL + A` to select all the text in a text box and delete it. What goes in the **Value** box?

This [article](http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2013/09/25/using-special-keys-in-selenium-ide-part-1/) isn't cutting it either.

[image: Selenium IDE Input]

Comment: using the `type` command can do just about the same thing. It replaces whatever is in the box. Should have read the reference material, but I am still interested in seeing how to chain key sequences.

Answer (score 0):

use command type, with value of ""

Comment: Good attempt, but I'm more curious to see if I can chain command keys together.

Comment: can you do: controlKeyDown()  keyPress("dom:document.body", "\97") controlKeyUp()

Comment: I'm only working with the IDE, not any language bindings. Sorry, I'm being super picky.